# Youtube embed display at one time start at beginning

Tags: wordpress, youtube, timestamp, embed

I am trying to embed a youtube video in my wordpress site and I would like to start it at the beginning but display it at another point for visuals, is this possible? I have looked online and in the youtube api with no luck..hoping Im missing it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always embed the visual and then allow the video to play with the click through from the beginning. You can get the visual to be a pretty high dpi as well so the quality remains in tact.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube only generates a few snapshots (around 1-3 snap images), there is no specific way to get an image at X point of time. It will be either a few seconds from the start, the middle and 1 other spot.

If you need to get the other format of the thumbnails, perhaps this can help

[Google Json String Query for Video](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=knH3kZSpocM&key=AIzaSyCx5zzkxfw0PhhkL765V6tnnqlTAj85r0Y&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status)